Axios becomes a promise
The console.log outputs of the api and axios variables in the following code are different, even though I didn't change anything. api is the normal axios but the state axios becomes a Promise.
import {createContext, useEffect, useState} from "react";
import api from "axios";


export const AxiosContext = createContext({
  axios: null
})

export const AxiosContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [axios, setAxios] = useState(api);
  
  console.log(api); // this is axios
  console.log(axios); // this is a Promise

  return(
    <AxiosContext.Provider value={{ axios }}>
      {children}
    </AxiosContext.Provider>
  )
}

Why does this happen? And how can I solve this problem?
Edit 1:
Thanks for the help my use case was that i passed a header with the authorization token to Axios. so, when someone logged in, it would update from the Axios instance without the token to one with the Bearer token throughout the application. However, I see the problem and will think on another solution.
Edit 2: I found a solution in: Axios Instance Bearer token not updated after login without reloading - React

There is absolutely no reason to store Axios in React state

This is caused by useState interpreting axios as an initialiser function. From the useState docs...

If you pass a function as initialState, it will be treated as an initializer function. It should be pure, should take no arguments, and should return a value of any type. React will call your initializer function when initializing the component, and store its return value as the initial state.

Since axios() returns a promise, that's the value you receive.
There is absolutely no reason to store an Axios instance as state; it doesn't ever need to be reactive to change.
I'd even go so far as to say there's little reason to supply it as context. If you must, just create an Axios instance and provide that as the context value
import axios from 'axios';

const instance = axios.create({ /* ... */ });

export const AxiosContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  return(
    <AxiosContext.Provider value={{ axios: instance }}>
      {children}
    </AxiosContext.Provider>
  );
}

Otherwise, just create an Axios instance in a module and import that where required
// services/api.js

import axios from 'axios';

export default axios.create({ /* ... */ });

// some other component
import api from './path/to/services/api';

